# Use separate docker container for code only

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Can I use one container for software (e.g. apache, php) and other container just for application code - /var/www/ folder ?

If so, how? Any caveats here?

I need it to speed up deployment - building full image takes more time as well as uploading, downloading full image on all instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

**Example(s):**

`docker-compose.yml:`

```
web:
    build: nginx
    volumes_from:
        - app
    ...

app:
    build: app
    ...
```

You would want your "nginx" `Dockerfile` to look like:

```
FROM nginx

VOLUME /var/www/html

...
```

Where `/var/www/html`` is part of your "app" container.

You would hack on "app" either locally and/or via Docker (`docker build app`, `docker run ... app`, etc).

When you're reasonably satisfied you can then test the whole integration by doing something like `docker-compose up`.